# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 table(interview and interviewtrack) in 1 form.

here's my savehandler code so far :

```
public function saveHandler(Request $request, $obj)
{
    try {
        DB::beginTransaction();
        $obj->fill($request->all());
        if (!$obj->save()) {
            throw new ValidationException($obj->errors());
        }
            foreach($request->interviewTracks as $interviewTrack) {
                \Log::info($interviewTrack);
                if (empty($interviewTrack['id'])) {
                    $interviewTrack = new InterviewTrack();
                }
                else {
                    $interviewTrack = InterviewTrack::find($interviewTrack['id']);
                }
                $interviewTrack->interview()->associate($obj);
                $interviewTrack['interview_id'] = isset($interviewTrack['interview_id']);
                $interviewTrack->status = $interviewTrack['status'];
                $interviewTrack->track_date = isset($interviewTrack['track_date']) ? $interviewTrack['start_time'] : 'YYYY-MM-DD';
                $interviewTrack->outcome = $interviewTrack['outcome'];
                $interviewTrack->remarks = $interviewTrack['remarks'];
                $interviewTrack->save();
            };
            if (!$interviewTrack->save()) {
                throw new ValidationException($interviewTrack->errors());
            }

        DB::commit();
        return $this->sendSuccessResponse($request);
    } catch (ValidationException $e) {
        DB::rollback();
        \Log::error($e->errors);
        return $this->sendErrorResponse($request, $e->errors);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        DB::rollback();
        \Log::error($e->getMessage());
        return $this->sendErrorResponse($request,'Unable to process. Please contact system Administrator');
    }

}
```

here's my view form code :

```
<?php $index = 0; ?> 
<?php echo Form::hidden('interviewTracks['.$index.'][id]', null); ?> 
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Track Date</label>
            <?php echo Form::text('interviewTracks['.$index.'][track_date]', null, ['id' => 'track_date','class' => 'form-control']); ?>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Status</label>
            <?php echo Form::select('interviewTracks['.$index.'][status]', $interviewTrackList, null, ['id' => 'status','class' => 'form-control']); ?>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Outcome</label>
            <?php echo Form::select('interviewTracks['.$index.'][outcome]', $outcomeList, null, ['id' => 'outcome','class' => 'form-control']); ?>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Remark</label>
            <?php echo Form::text('interviewTracks['.$index.'][remark]', null, ['id' => 'remarks','class' => 'form-control']); ?>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php $index++; ?>
```

it throws error Invalid argument supplied for foreach() when I try to save.
any idea ??

Comment: dd($request->all()) ... and inspect the result.

Comment: can't get intertrack field values.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

`foreach($request->interviewTracks as $interviewTrack)`

to:

`foreach($request->input('interviewTracks') as $interviewTrack)`